# Is there a way to convert data from pdf to a Matlab-compatible file?

Tags: matlab, pdf

[image]

Assuming the previous pic, from a relatively olf-format pdf. Is there any way to extract the data and convert it into a Matlab-friendly file (txt, etc.) all together without having to go through all the entries by hand?

Comment: Does copy and paste work? If so text information is present in the document. Otherwise you would have to get some OCR software to recognize the characters.

Comment: copy and paste does not work unfortunately. I will check what OCR is.